# A property of absolutely continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis

It is remarked by some text book that according to definition of absolutely continuous functions if the finite sums in the definition are replaced by the sums of (infinite) countable items, the assertion still holds. But I don't know why, even I understand that the number of the finite items is arbitrary.
Any comments are welcomed. S.C.Liu

Answer (score 6):

The standard definition of absolute continuity of a real-valued function $f$ defined on an interval is that for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that whenever $I_k = (a_k, b_k)$ for $k=1,\ldots,n$ is a disjoint collection of subintervals of $I$ with $\sum_{k=1}^n (b_k-a_k) < \delta$ one has $\sum_{k=1}^n |f(b_k) - f(a_k)| < \epsilon$.

Now if $I_k = (a_k, b_k)$ for $k=1,2,\ldots$ is an infinite disjoint collection of subintervals with $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (b_k - a_k)<\delta$, then this is also true for the partial sums, and so by absolute continuity applied to the intervals $I_k$ for $k = 1, \ldots, n$ you get $\sum_{k=1}^n |f(b_k)-f(a_k)|< \epsilon$ for all $n$. Passing to the limit gives $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |f(b_k) - f(a_k)| \le \epsilon$, so apart from the (non-essential) difference between $<$ and $\le$ exactly the same statement.